# Formated price coming in round figure,

Tags: magento2, price, email

I am using below code to show price in Email template magento 2.X

```
$this->priceFormatter($_item->getPrice()
```

Instead in price coming 0.73 it is coming 8, Can anyone have suggetion, Please share.

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the applicable code. This snippet should throw an error and seems to be missing some relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use

```
sprintf("%.2f €", $_item->getPrice());
```

This way you can easily control your price output.

Comment: but it is taking euro....My site have both $ and euro....currency can be switched at time of order creation

Comment: mmm then try to dig down and go back to `priceFormatter()`'s declaration. See what can be done, override it if need be.

Comment: You have an idea for current currency sysmbol?